# Loop back mode enabling?

Tags: c, embedded, linux-device-driver, uart

I want the software loop back to be tested using my application code  for uart4 instance of omap-4460.I am using the default driver.

How will I do it using ioctl?or any other way.

Please find the driver code here [omap-serial.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/serial/omap-serial.c?v=3.4).

Please share any reference code.

Comment: Short out pins 2 & 3 - it's easier.

Comment: @MartinJames:But I want the software loop back to be tested using my application code.There is a MCR register which enables this loopback.Do you have any idea for setting this MCR[4] bit through user application code?

Comment: Use the **TIOCM_LOOP** bit-parameter in a sequence of `ioctl()` calls.       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059104/rs-232-pin-configuration-in-linux-pc